# Connecting external Tomcat console to NetBeans 7.0+

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have installed Tomcat Separately from NetBeans. Then I connect my NetBeans to Tomcat and everything is working well. I can deploy project, run them and so on. The only one problem that I have is I can't see System.out.println(); console message anywhere. My colleagues installed Tomcat directly from NetBeans and they have the console. Why I don't have it and how  I'm supposed to debug without this console.

Answer (score 0):

You probably closed that console and you can't see it. 
Open `Netbeans` and go to: `Window -> Output -> Output` or just click `Alt + 6` and the console will be opened.

Comment: I see the console, but it is empty. The last line in console is "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" and no one message from System.out.println();

Comment: Do you see something in server output console?

Answer (score 0):

If you register the Tomcat instance in the NetBeans server list, there will be a new "Tomcat" node in the server list, which has a context menu. For many servers, this menu includes a menu item which displays the server console output / log: `'View Server Log'` and `'View Server Output'`.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 option but....again can't see anything from System.out. Temporary I solve my solution by Installing Tomcat directly from NetBeans. So for now I haven't manage to link external TomCat with NetBeans